# Null Reference Error while accessing SharePoint Navigation Settings

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am getting System.NullReferenceException while accessing some of site settings of SharePoint web application from siteaction menu . I have attached the screen shot of error which I am getting in Navigation Page (i.e. _layouts/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx) of SharePoint site.
[image: Error which I am getting while accessing site Navigation page (i.e. AreaNavigationSettings.aspx)]

Can anyone let me know the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved now.

Solution:

To get into details of this error I have enabled debug attribute of compilation attribute of system.web tag to true in config of my SharePoint site website. After doing that I came to know the exact line number at which I was getting this NullReferenceException.

On that line, we are displaying Site updated date in page. To display date, we are using 'Modified' field of page. As I have indicated in my comments, we have restored the site from crashed backup anyhow this modified property was causing issue for application pages and giving us NullReferenceException.

We have removed Modified date display portion from Master Page and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be that you don't have the publishing features activated in your site or simply your site is not a publishing one. Could you check if under Site --> Settings you have a Navigation option?

[image]

If you don't have it is normal to get that error

Comment: Yes 'Navigation' option is already enable for this SharePoint site but still I am getting this error.

Comment: Try to create a Publishing site in an independet site collection. If still is not working create a new Web Application and Publishing Top level site Site collection. Are you getting the same results?

Comment: I have restored this site from the backup which we have recovered after server crash. If I create new web application and check the navigation settings then it is working fine but I want to resolve the issue for this site (i.e. which I have recovered from crash)